# Does this hinged tiling have a name?

Tags: tiling, tessellations

This hinged tessellation is made of rectangles centred on a triangular lattice.
Does anyone know if it has a name or has any reference to some paper which studied this configuration or other info such as which wallpaper group it belongs to etc?
Anything related would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: By using [the wallpaper group guide on the wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallpaper_group#Guide_to_recognizing_wallpaper_groups) the group is easily seen to be _pgg_.